# SQL / ActiveRecord Query for Multiple Rows on Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say that I have two ActiveRecord models (or two tables in an SQL database, if you'd like). I have a `User` class and a `Poll` class. A `User` has_many `Polls`. When a user takes a `Poll`, they are asked whether or not they like `apples`, `bananas`, and `cherries`. The `User`'s response to each of these things is recorded in a boolean column.

I'm interested in finding out which users have taken `Polls` and have responded that they like each of `apples`, `bananas`, and `cherries` at ANY time (not necessarily at the same time). Put differently, they do not need to have said that they like all three fruits during one `Poll`, they just need to have said that they like each of these things at some point, i.e. they need to have said that they like `apples` in at least one `Poll`, `bananas` in at least one `Poll`, and `cherries` in at least one `Poll`.

What's the right way to go about doing this in a general manner? Either an ActiveRecord or SQL query would be helpful.

Comment: Have you made any attempts to sort this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets suppose your `polls` table has boolean columns `apples`, `bananas`, and `cherries`. Then for each user, you want to look at the corresponding polls and compute an aggregate OR function on each fruit column, keeping only the rows that return true for each fruit.

```
User.joins(:polls)
    .group('users.id')
    .having('BOOL_OR(polls.apples) = ? AND BOOL_OR(polls.bananas) = ? AND BOOL_OR(polls.cherries) = ?', true, true, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps your table looks like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c0967/10:

```
create table polls (userid char(10), pollid char(10), questionid char(10), response boolean);

insert into polls (userid, pollid, questionid, response)
values ('1','1','APPLES',true),
       ('1','1','BANANAS',false),
       ('1','1','CHERRIES',true),
       ('1','2','APPLES',false),
       ('1','2','BANANAS',false),
       ('1','2','CHERRIES',true),
       ('1','3','APPLES',false),
       ('1','3','BANANAS',true),
       ('1','3','CHERRIES',true),
       ('2','1','APPLES',false),
       ('2','1','BANANAS',false),
       ('2','1','CHERRIES',true),
       ('2','2','APPLES',false),
       ('2','2','BANANAS',true),
       ('2','2','CHERRIES',true),
       ('2','3','APPLES',false),
       ('2','3','BANANAS',false),
       ('2','3','CHERRIES',true),
       ('3','1','APPLES',true),
       ('3','1','BANANAS',false),
       ('3','1','CHERRIES',false),
       ('3','2','APPLES',false),
       ('3','2','BANANAS',true),
       ('3','2','CHERRIES',false),
       ('3','3','APPLES',false),
       ('3','3','BANANAS',false),
       ('3','3','CHERRIES',true),
       ('4','1','APPLES',false),
       ('4','1','BANANAS',false),
       ('4','1','CHERRIES',false),
       ('4','2','APPLES',true),
       ('4','2','BANANAS',true),
       ('4','2','CHERRIES',true),
       ('4','3','APPLES',false),
       ('4','3','BANANAS',false),
       ('4','3','CHERRIES',false)
;
```

in which case you can create a temporary view grouping the user questions with true responses, and then count the records in that view like this:

```
with counts as (
  select userid, questionid
  from polls
  where response = true
  and questionid in ('APPLES','BANANAS','CHERRIES')
  group by userid, questionid
  )
select userid
from counts
group by userid
having count(*) = 3
```